# Creating a stack of photos with UICollectionView which a user can swipe through

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am attempting to create a stack of photos using `UICollectionView` in which a user can swipe a photo to the side. As a photo is dragged, it gets smaller (to a minimum scale) and the photo behind is enlarged to a maximum scale. This maximum scale is the original size of the foreground photo.

When the pan gesture which drags the foreground photo ends, if it is the minimum scale, it is sent to the back of the stack, otherwise, it is animated back to the centre of the screen and enlarged back to its original size (along with the growing photo behind it).

I hope you're still with me haha.

Now, assuming the photo being dragged is at its minimum size, I remove user interaction of the `UICollectionView`, animate the photo to the centre of the screen again, and its size is animated to match the rest of the background images. I then send the cell to the back of the `UICollectionView`s subviews.

Once all of these animations have taken place, I update my data source (an array of images) by adding the photo in front to the back, then deleting that photo at the front.

Then, I update the `UICollectionView`. This consists of a batch update in which I delete the item at an `NSIndexPath` of 0 : 0, then, insert an item at `NSIndexPath` ([photo count] - 1) : 0.

When this batch update finished, I reload my `UICollectionView` (as only the item at `NSIndexPath` 0 : 0 has a pan gesture) and re-add user interaction to the `UICollectionView`.

I hope this makes sense.

**Notes**

The size of the background photos is a percent of 80%.

The size of the foreground photo is a percent of 100%.

This is relative to the `UICollectionView` which fits the screen of the iPhone.

**My problem**

My code seems to work very well. My issue comes from when I take my finger off the screen (the pan gesture ends) and the animation of the photo (centring it to the centre of the screen and sizing it like the rest of the background photos) ends.

The photo dragged off reappears on screen, sizes from the size of the background photos (80%) to the size of the foreground photo (100%) then fades away. Once this happens the photos are reordered as expected.

Does anyone know why this might happen?

**Here is my Pan Gesture code:**

```
CGPoint touchTranslation = [gesture translationInView:self.view];

static CGPoint originalCenter;

DIGalleryCollectionViewLayout *galleryCollectionViewLayout = (DIGalleryCollectionViewLayout *)self.galleryCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;

if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    //
    //  Began.
    //
    originalCenter = gesture.view.center;
} else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    //
    //  Changed.
    //
    CGPoint translate = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view.superview];

    touchTranslation = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translate.x, originalCenter.y + translate.y);
    [gesture.view setCenter:touchTranslation];

    CGPoint pointsPhotoIsMovedBy = CGPointMake(fabsf(fabsf(originalCenter.x) - fabsf(touchTranslation.x)),
                                               fabsf(fabsf(originalCenter.y) - fabsf(touchTranslation.y)));

    //  Update cells.
    //
    CGFloat currentIncrement = MAX(pointsPhotoIsMovedBy.x, pointsPhotoIsMovedBy.y);

    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.galleryCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems) {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.galleryCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if ([indexPath isEqual:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]]) {
            //
            //      Front.
            //
            CGFloat frontScalePercent = MIN(GalleryCollectionViewLayoutFrontRatioDefault,
                                            MAX(GalleryViewFrontScaleMinimum, GalleryCollectionViewLayoutFrontRatioDefault - (currentIncrement / 250.0f)));

            [cell setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(frontScalePercent, frontScalePercent)];
        } else if ([indexPath isEqual:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:0]]) {
            //
            //      Next.
            //
            CGFloat nextScalePercent = MAX(GalleryCollectionViewLayoutBackRatioDefault,
                                           MIN(GalleryViewNextScaleMaximum, (currentIncrement / 150.0f)));

            [cell setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(nextScalePercent, nextScalePercent)];
        } else {
            //
            //      Background.
            //
            [cell setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(GalleryCollectionViewLayoutBackRatioDefault,
                                                          GalleryCollectionViewLayoutBackRatioDefault)];
        }
    }
} else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    //
    //  Ended.
    //
    if (gesture.view.transform.a == GalleryViewFrontScaleMinimum) {
        //
        //  Next photo.
        //
        [self.galleryCollectionView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [self.galleryCollectionView sendSubviewToBack:gesture.view];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                         animations:^{
                             [gesture.view setCenter:self.galleryCollectionView.center];
                             [gesture.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(GalleryCollectionViewLayoutBackRatioDefault,
                                                                                   GalleryCollectionViewLayoutBackRatioDefault)];
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             //
                             //          Data source
                             //
                             NSMutableArray *photos = [self.photos mutableCopy];

                             [photos addObject:[photos objectAtIndex:0]];
                             [photos removeObjectAtIndex:0];

                             [self setPhotos:photos];

                             //          Contents
                             //
                             [self.galleryCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                                 [self.galleryCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]]];
                                 [self.galleryCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:(self.photos.count - 1) inSection:0]]];
                             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                 [self.galleryCollectionView reloadData];

                                 [self.galleryCollectionView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                             }];
                         }];
    } else {
        //
        //  Stay.
        //
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
                             //
                             // Front cell.
                             //
                             [gesture.view setCenter:self.galleryCollectionView.center];
                             [gesture.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(GalleryCollectionViewLayoutFrontRatioDefault,
                                                                                   GalleryCollectionViewLayoutFrontRatioDefault)];

                             // Next cell.
                             //
                             for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.galleryCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems) {
                                 if ([indexPath isEqual:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:0]]) {
                                     //
                                     //      Next.
                                     //
                                     UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.galleryCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                                     [cell setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(GalleryCollectionViewLayoutBackRatioDefault,
                                                                                   GalleryCollectionViewLayoutBackRatioDefault)];
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [galleryCollectionViewLayout setFrontRatio:GalleryCollectionViewLayoutFrontRatioDefault];
                             [galleryCollectionViewLayout setNextRatio:GalleryCollectionViewLayoutBackRatioDefault];
                             [galleryCollectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
                         }];
    }
}
```

**And here is my prepareLayout: code for the collection view layout:**

```
NSMutableDictionary *newLayoutInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary *cellLayoutInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

NSIndexPath *indexPath;

for (NSInteger section = 0; section < [self.collectionView numberOfSections]; section++) {
    NSInteger itemCount = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];

    for (NSInteger item = 0; item < itemCount; item++) {
        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];

        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *itemAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];

        [itemAttributes setSize:[self sizeForPhotoAtIndexPath:indexPath inContainerOfSize:self.collectionView.bounds.size]];
        [itemAttributes setCenter:self.collectionView.center];

        //  Z Index.
        //
        NSInteger zIndex = itemCount - item;
        [itemAttributes setZIndex:zIndex];

        //  Scale cells based on z position.
        //
        if (zIndex == itemCount) {
            //
            //      Foreground.
            //
            [itemAttributes setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(self.frontRatio, self.frontRatio)];
        } else if (zIndex == itemCount - 1) {
            //
            //      Next.
            //
            [itemAttributes setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(self.nextRatio, self.nextRatio)];
        } else {
            //
            //      Background.
            //
            [itemAttributes setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(GalleryCollectionViewLayoutBackRatioDefault,
                                                                    GalleryCollectionViewLayoutBackRatioDefault)];
        }

        cellLayoutInfo[indexPath] = itemAttributes;
    }
}

newLayoutInfo[GalleryCollectionViewLayoutCellKind] = cellLayoutInfo;

self.layoutInfo = newLayoutInfo;
```

**And as an additional reference, here is my code for sizeForPhotoAtIndexPath: inContainerOfSize:**

```
UIImage *photo = [[(DIGalleryViewController *)self.collectionView.delegate photos] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

CGSize size = CGSizeMake(photo.size.width, photo.size.height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(containerSize);
[photo drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, containerSize.width, containerSize.height)];
UIImage *resizedPhoto = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGFloat ratio = photo.size.width / resizedPhoto.size.width;

size = CGSizeMake(resizedPhoto.size.width, photo.size.height / ratio);

return size;
```

Comment: I should also point out that in the `setPhotos:` method I am NOT calling `reloadData` on the `UICollectionView`

Comment: My understanding is that the problem comes from `prepareLayout`. I think the transforms which take place in this method are somehow being reapplied

Comment: My new theory is based on the fact that during the pan gesture, the cell is being resized on its `transform` property, however, in `prepareLayout` the transforms are based on the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`.